# Global variable containing comma is not being recognized

Tags: stata

My root directory contains things like `.`  and `,`

So if I write

```
global root "C:/Users/Owner/0. Lyx,R/2000, AAA/"
global data1 "${root}Data\"
use ${data1}data
```

then it says

```
invalid 'Lyx'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As my answer to the other question explains, you need to use double quotes in `use` to take into account the spaces. Commas and periods have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @PearlySpencer I already tried double quotes but that didn't work. It seemed Stata considers `,` inside the double quotes as something non-literally-texual

Comment: This does not make sense. On my computer with the same directory names I cannot replicate the problem. Everything works fine.

Comment: You need to use double quotes as follows: `use "${data1}data"`

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @PearlySpencer Yes I  think I was just mistaken in the first place.